# How can I make "git push production" push all files in repository?

Tags: laravel, git

Setting up a new laravel server I see that not all files are pushed.

I set up a bare repo, according to the instrctions in:https://devmarketer.io/learn/deploy-laravel-5-app-lemp-stack-ubuntu-nginx/  (step 11 and following)

The first time it pushed a lot of files.
The css and js files that were added to the /resources later, are not pushed anymore.
/resources is not in .gitignore, so they should be pushed.

They are there in the local repo, but not on the remote.

How can I solve this?

Can anyone help me ( noob, makes stupid errors) analyse the situation?

.gitignore:

```
/node_modules
/public/storage
/vendor
/.idea
Homestead.json
Homestead.yaml
.env
.*.swp
public/js
public/css
```

Comment: You probably need a build command of some kind after the deployment, to generate the public/js and public/css files. Typically this is done with Laravel Mix.

Comment: Yes, it is the resource files that are missing. Public is supposed to be

Comment: Well, you've got `public/js` and `public/css` in your `.gitignore`. That means they are ignored, and that's why they're not getting included.

Comment: I do understand. But I am missing RESOURCES/app.js and /RESOURCES/css

Those are not in the .gitignore.

Comment: How are you determining that they're missing?

Comment: I go there in the terminal, #ls -al shows a list, with directories missing. When I delete a directory it is not replaced after the next push either...

and I just see the lousy layout of my website and non functioning buttons that depend on js-scripts..

Answer (score 2):

Files or folders listed in your .gitignore are ignored by git, therefore won't be pushed into your remote repo. All other files should get pushed just fine.

Comment: indeed, It are the js and css form the  /resouces directory that are not pushed...
therefore the public files are not generated.

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

```
 git push production new-branch
 git checkout master
 git merge new-branch
 git push production master
```

Can anyone see what the problem was? I still do not understand what went wrong...